# Edge :focus styles

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, sass, accessibility

Trying to get the pseudo class :focus to work in Edge. This is working in Chrome and Firefox, but for ADA reasons, need it to work in Edge.  I can get :active and :hover to work, but what I need is :focus to work for keyboard navigation.  This is what I've tried:

```
/* Microsoft EdgeV13&14 CSS styles go here */
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  div {
   &:focus {
    background: green;
   }
  }
 }
```

And variations with the @supports tag. And as an FYI I need to target just as we are leaving how the other browsers handle their focus. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I'm also open to using jQuery if that is the best route for this.

For reference, this is this best I could find on focusing on just the Edge browser:

https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/css-hacks-for-windows-10-and-spartan-browser-preview/

Comment: *"...in IE Edge."* There is no "IE Edge." Edge is not a version of IE. It's a *replacement* for IE. And indeed, IE-specific hacks will not work in Edge. Perhaps that relates to your issue...

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I thought the -ms-ime-align was for Edge. This does work in Edge for :hover and :active.

Comment: According to MDN, [that property is supported by Edge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-ime-align). I'm just saying, generally, IE-specific hacks don't work on Edge. (Microsoft-specific ones, such as prefixed property names, may or may not depending... :-) )

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot its not IE Edge so that may help my searching a bit.

Comment: Edge is supposed to support all pseudo classes from the CSS 2.1 spec, including `:focus`. Wouldn't be surprised if there are some bugs, but after running a few (very) quick tests my Edge 16 behaves consistent with FF and Chrome in the way content is `:focus`ed. Are you able to provide a working sample?

Comment: @agrm https://blackbeardiner.com/. In chrome and ff this the default blue/gray outline. The links do show focus, but not any div or menu items.

Comment: Thanks. To be frank, there's no focus effect in FF either. It seems the default `:focus` is overridden. First it's set to `outline: 0` in style.css. In bootstrap.min.css the outline is set with `outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color`. As `-webkit-focus-ring-color` isn't recognized by Firefox and Edge, the whole declaration is ignored. The color and text-decoration applied in the same style sheet appears to be ignored/overridden because of specificity.

Comment: I wouldn't go with `!important` for anything but debugging, but see if this gets you a consistent result: `:focus { outline: 2px solid red!important; }`